# error: base operand of ‘->’ has non-pointer type ‘cv::Mat’

Tags: c++, opencv, c-api

i have a c-Api opencv project and i want to change into c++ (mat)
see this original code :

```
current_cost = 0;
basePtr = (unsigned char*)tmp1->imageData;
for( int j=0; j<tmp1->height; basePtr += tmp1->widthStep, j++ )
{
    iterator = basePtr;
    for( int i=0; i<tmp1->width; iterator++, i++ )
        if( *iterator == 255 )
            current_cost++;
}

basePtr = (unsigned char*)tmp2->imageData;
for( int j=0; j < tmp2->height; basePtr += tmp2->widthStep, j++ )
{
    iterator = basePtr;
    for( int i=0; i<tmp2->width; iterator++, i++ )
        if( *iterator == 0 )
            current_cost++;
}
if( current_cost < cost )                
    return true;
else return false;
```

after run this project , see this error

```
main.cpp:63:35: error: base operand of ‘->’ has non-pointer type ‘cv::Mat’
 basePtr = (unsigned char*)tmp1->imageData;
```

see error for every line used '->' . 
please help me ...

Comment: The error is telling you that the tmp1 (and so on) is not a POINTER, but instead has the type cv::Mat. So, in this case, I'll assume that the correct form to deal with this is like tmp1.imageData (and so on). But this is a guess, as you aren't showing enough of your code.

Comment: try using `tmp1.imageData`

Answer (score 0):

You should not merely convert each code line, but use the C++ api smartly. Your function could be rewritten simply as:

```
bool foo(const Mat& tmp1, const Mat& tmp2, int cost) {
    int count = countNonZero(tmp1 == 255);
    count += countNonZero(tmp2 == 0);
    return count < cost;
}
```